# text overflow from div

Tags: css, overflow

I want a static width for main div as 300px. But when any users copy and paste text from Word program, then change table width and overflow text from div. But width of my site must be max 300px. How can I solve this problem?

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#main td{
max-width:300px;
}

#main table{
max-width:300px;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="main">
<table width="700" border="1">
<tr>
<td width="800"><p width="900">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="800"><p with="900">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
#main table{
max-width:300px;
}
```

To

```
#main *{
max-width:300px;
}
```

That way, the TD, img and others will still be sized. Also, you could use `overflow-x:hidden` on your `#main` div to hide the content that is too big to fit.

Comment: But I don't want hide overflow text. End of the div sentence will go down to the bottom line?

Comment: dont use overflow:hidden then. Not sure what you mean by your 2nd sentence

Comment: like this; 1asdadad 2asdadad 3asdadasd 4asdasdasd 4 word a sentence. After 2 word third word will bottom line?

Comment: yes it should. Only problematic will be if they do not put spaces. Like a very long URL.

Comment: your welcome. remember to choose my answer if it correctly answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend  doing some type of sanitation on  the Word text to remove unwanted inline styles.  You shoul always sanitize text coming from word to the web anyways.  You could use something like tinyIMCE or similar.  That way you don't have to worry about what they copy, it will always obey the CSS.

Comment: yes you are right about editor and I use cke already. But still take issue